# EF6 add-migration file econding

Tags: encoding, utf-8, visual-studio-2015, entity-framework-6

How I can change default encoding of newly generated file by add-migration from ANSI to UTF8?

Iam looking for a solution that will work every time new file is created after add-migration. Changing encoding in visual studio for each migration is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

One idea would be to write an MSBUILD, Grunt, or Gulp task which ran pre-compilation. It would have to detect whether a file is UTF8 and re-save it if it isn't. That way, you'll never have to do any actual work, and the project will 'self-correct'.

Otherwise, I guess you'd have to alter the template used to scaffold migrations on your machine and on every other developer's machine, which seems to introduce some instability into everyone's VS installation, which I wouldn't advise.